# Seeding If Else Conditionals in C

Tags: c, if-statement

Im writing this program in C and Im having a big problem when I compile it, once I get to the part were I ask the user if hes under 21, if the answer is yes, I ask more questions about that, but when I compile it, the program basicly answers its self. how can I fix this plz?
heres a screenshot, the orange box, i did not answer any of those questions. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6U6K.png

Comment: Well I don't know C, but it looks like you are only setting the value of `a` once at the start of your script as far as I can see.

Comment: printing a question != asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the branch you're having trouble with, you're forgetting to prompt the user for input. Hence, it's reusing whichever answer was last given by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to ask the user for input after each question except the first one. Just do `scanf("%c", &a);` after each question.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the same variable,`a`, without actually asking for the user input to put into `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You only read information from the user once.  You need to do a scanf before each

```
if (a == 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

only one scanf() function was using which means only once input is acceptable from the stdin stream. for scanf(), when press "enter", the stream stack to 'a'. then stdin stream is NULL. so before each question, should use scanf() once.